# "context" argument of Firebase.on is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase

"context" is 4th arguments of Firebase.on

```
on(eventType, callback, [cancelCallback], [context])
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html

> context Object *optional
>
> If provided, this object will be used as this when calling your callback.

But it seems like not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>firebase sample</title>

  <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    (function () {
      var listener = {
        onChildAdded: function (snapshot) {
          console.log(this);
        }
      };
      console.log(listener);

      var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR_FIREBASE_APP>.firebaseio.com");
      ref.on("child_added", listener.onChildAdded, null, listener);
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected: Object (`{ onChildAdded: function... }`)

Result  : Window (browser global object)

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFW93.png)

So I solved this problem with `bind` method.

```
ref.on("child_added", listener.onChildAdded.bind(listener));
```

Is this problem a bug or spec?

Comment: which version of firebase are you using?

Comment: I use firebase 2.2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually according to source code optional `cancel` callback should be omitted not provided a `null`/`undefined` value. This may be not evident from docs but `cancel` IS optional

Comment: Thanks! Surely it works well, but it isn't documented. I think it is not reasonable and not user-friendly api.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is if the 3rd param is null it is not considering the 4th param so try to pass an empty function as the 3rd param

```
ref.on("child_added", listener.onChildAdded, function(){}, listener);
```

Comment: Thanks! Surely it works well, but it isn't documented.
I think it is not reasonable and not user-friendly api.